# If...else statements to check for NaN and empty string not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, fizzbuzz

I refactored FizzBuzz using functions and everything is working great except for two if..else statements in the function meant to validate the user's input (validateValue). I want to alert users that empty strings, decimals and NaN are not allowed. The statement checking for decimals works, but not empty strings or NaN. When I enter an empty string or NaN, the prompt for no decimals appears. I want to fix this using vanilla JavaScript, no jQuery.

Here is the JavaScript:

```
function getValue(message) {
  var msg = "Please enter a number from 1 to 100.";
  if (message) {
    msg = message;
  }
    return parseInt(prompt(msg)); 
}

function validateValue(num) { 
  if (num === "") { 
    return getValue("Please type something."); 
  } else if (num%1 !== 0) { 
    return getValue("No decimals allowed."); 
  } else if (isNaN(num)) { 
    return getValue("That is not a number!"); 
  } else {
    return num; 
  }
}

function fizzBuzz(num) {
   for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
   if (i%15 === 0) {
    document.getElementById("list").innerHTML += "FizzBuzz<br>";
   }
   else if (i%3 === 0) {
    document.getElementById("list").innerHTML += "Fizz<br>";
  }
  else if (i%5 === 0) {
    document.getElementById("list").innerHTML += "Buzz<br>";
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("list").innerHTML += i + "<br>";
  }
}
}

  var value = validateValue(getValue());
  fizzBuzz(value);
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>FizzBuzz Refactor</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <p>Your FizzBuzz results:</p>
    <ul id="list">
    </ul>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, for starters, `NaN % 1` yields `NaN`, and `NaN !== 0` is `true`, so `NaN % 1 !== 0` is also `true`.

Comment: `num` is something already processed by `parseInt`, so it cannot be `""`

Comment: You never a get an empty string inside of `validateValue`, because you've already called `parseInt`

Comment: as @charlietfl pointed out, you are checking for decimals after running `parseInt`, so "`checking for decimals works`" is not exactly true - decimals seem to be accepted without validation and truncated to integers

Comment: you don't  validate the 2nd input when 1st is invalid - is that intentional or how many times do you want to prompt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want something like:

```
function validateValue(num) {
  if (num === "") {
    return getValue("Please type something."); 
  }

  num = parseFloat(num);

  if (isNaN(num)) {
    return getValue("That is not a number!"); 
  } else if (num%1 !== 0) { 
    return getValue("No decimals allowed."); 
  } else {
    return num; 
  }
}
```

A string can't be a NaN. So you need to try to convert it to a number before you check if it's NaN.

Comment: Decimal conditional won't work using `parseInt` beforehand

Comment: In that case, you can use parseFloat instead. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```js
function validate(str) {
  if (validateEmpty(str)) {
    console.log("Input is emply");
  } else if (validateNum(str)) {
    console.log("Value is numeric");
  } else {
    console.log("Invalid Input");
  }
}

function validateEmpty(str) {
  return str === undefined || str == null || str.toString().trim().length === 0;
}

function validateNum(str) {
  var reg = /[0-9]/i;
  return reg.test(str);
}

(function() {
  var a = "";
  validate(a);
  a = "123.46";
  validate(a);
  a = "123.46.57";
  validate(a);
  a = "absl123.46.57";
  validate(a);
  a = "test";
  validate(a);
})()
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone! Here's my solution, commented out:

```
function getValue(message) {
  var msg = "Please enter a number from 1 to 100."; // default message
  if (message) {
    msg = message;
  }
    return prompt(msg); // return prompt with appropriate message based on value
}

function validateValue(num) {
  if (num === "") {
    return getValue("Please type something."); // check for empty string
  }

  num = parseFloat(num); // converts string to floating number

  if (isNaN(num)) {
    return getValue("That is not a number!"); // check for NaN
  } else if (num%1 !== 0) { 
    return getValue("No decimals allowed."); // check for decimals
  } else {
    return num; 
  }
}
```